# customClass in Angularjs uib-datepicker depends on a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, promise

I'm using Angularjs [UI bootstap datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), and trying to set custom classes for certain days, as it's shown at the example on the provided page

this is a part of mine controller

```
var vm = this;
...
vm.dateOptions = {
        customClass: getTestDaysClass;
};
...
function getTestDaysClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.testDays.length; i++) {
            var currentDat = new Date(vm.testDays[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
            if (dayToCheck === currentDat) {
                return vm.testDays[i].status;
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

And HTML

```
<uib-datepicker 
        datepicker-options="user.dateOptions">
</uib-datepicker>
```

The problem is that the array `vm.testDays` I get from the back-end call from the service. And it isn't in the controller's scope yet, when the page is loaded, so the application crashes with the [following error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=HomeUserController&p1=not%20a).
Could you give me a hint how to solve this? Some way to make a datepicker to wait for the promise to resolve.

Comment: Since `uib-datepicker` directive doesn't bind `datepicker-options`, it should be compiled after options object is formed. Consider using a route/state resolver to retrieve service data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I used the **"ng-if"** tag into a wrapper div with a variable that changed its value to true when I had got the dates.

**In the html:**

```
<div ng-if="calendarLoaded">
    <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></uib-datepicker>
</div>
```

**In my directive:**

```
$scope.calendarLoaded = false;
$http.get(...)
.then(function(response)
{
  $scope.calendarLoaded = true;
  {... other code here ...}
});
```

I hope this can help you.